# onCreateOptionsMenu is called when a fragment from backstack becomes visible, but old menu objects are still present

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

When I'm inflating a menu with a `SearchView` for the first time, I retain `MenuItem` and `SearchView` references to call `expandactionView()` programmatically and also to set a `OnQueryTextListener`.
When a fragment with this `SearchView` goes into backstack and gives and an another fragment with it's own menu comes visible and some time routing back to the fragment with this `SearchView` is performed, `onCreateOptionsMenu` is being called, of course.
But here is a problem: there is an **old** `SearchView` is being retained.
Here's a code of `onCreateOptionsMenu` of the "search" fragment:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
    menu?.clear()
    inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.menu_scenarios, menu)
    val menuItem: MenuItem = menu!!.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView: SearchView = menuItem.actionView!! as SearchView
    view.withSearchView(menuItem, searchView)
    addOnQueryListener(searchView)
    setSignalingExpandListener()
}
```

When I call `expandActionView()` programmatically, it is another, new `MenuItemImpl` is being expanded, and old one, that somewhy gets retained, is not expanded on the screen. Subsequently, when I tap on the search icon afterwards, it is the old one `MenuItem` who receives the request (was verified with debugger).
How to resolve this problem? I need a single `SearchView`, be it the old one or the new one (does not matter).

P.S.: view is just my "proxy" object for the visible elements on the screen. Internally `withSearchView` works like this:

```
fun withSearchView(menuItem: MenuItem, searchView: SearchView) {
    this.menuItem = menuItem
    this.searchView = searchView
}
```